# Failed to run graph using PhilJay/MPAndroidChart library for android

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}

compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

BarChart chart;
ArrayList<BarEntry> entries;
ArrayList<String> labels;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barChartId);

    entries = new ArrayList<>();

    labels = new ArrayList<>();

    entries.add(new BarEntry(2f, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(7f, 4));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(3f, 5));

    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");

    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "Projects");

    BarData barData = new BarData(labels, barDataSet);

    barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    chart.setData(barData);

    chart.animateY(3000);

}
```

Error : 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method (FI)V in class Lcom/github/mikephil/charting/data/BarEntry;

Comment: At which line error occurs?

Comment: Add tag mpandroidchart, and dveloper of this library will reply soon. Also tell me at which line error occured. Kindly, please.

Comment: Error occur at this line 30 where code is entries.add(new BarEntry(2f, 0)). There is no compile error rather app crash at run time.

Comment: Do you have jar file in libs folder? I am using the library by adding jar file in libs, then setting build.gradle as : `compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-2-4.jar')`, I see we both have same versions, mine works fine.

Comment: I have include compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4' inside dependencies instead adding library.

Comment: Try removing 'f' from `2f` and all others in `entries.add(new BarEntry(2f, 0))`.

Comment: you mean removing f like this entries.add(new BarEntry(2, 0)) well this also doesn't help still appearing error.